# Creating more objects dynamically

Tags: c#, object, dynamic

So my idea here is to create more instances of the class Runner, but when I do this and list all the objects that I created, they are all the last one I created. I understand that this is cause objects are reference type. But is there any way I can do this?

```
class Marathon
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List < Runner > athleteList = new List<Runner>();
        int opcao=0;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1-Registar Atleta Profissional\n2-Registar Atleta Amador\n3-Registar Fancy Dresser\n4-Listar Atletas Inscritos\n5-Registar Fim de prova de um atleta\n6-Sair");
            opcao = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch(opcao)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Introduza o numero do Atleta:");
                    int numeroAtletaP = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Introduza o ranking to atleta:");
                    int rankingAtletaP = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    athleteList.Add(new Professional(rankingAtletaP,numeroAtletaP));

                    break;

                case 2:
                    SponsorshipForm spFa = new SponsorshipForm();
                    Console.WriteLine("Introduza o numero do Atleta:");
                    int numeroAtletaA = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    athleteList.Add(new Amateur(numeroAtletaA,spFa));
                    break;

                case 3:
                    SponsorshipForm spfFD = new SponsorshipForm();
                    Console.WriteLine("Introduza o numero do Atleta:");
                    int numeroAtletaFD = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Costume:");
                    string costume =Console.ReadLine();
                    athleteList.Add(new FancyDresser(numeroAtletaFD, spfFD, costume));
                    break;

                case 4:
                    foreach (Runner athlete in athleteList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(athlete.toString());
                    }
                    break;

                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine("Introduza o numero do Atleta:");
                    int numeroAtleta = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    foreach (Runner athlete in athleteList)
                    {
                        if (numeroAtleta == athlete.getNumber())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Hora chegada:");
                            int horaChegada = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.WriteLine("Minuto chegada:");
                            int minutoChegada = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.WriteLine("Segundo chegada:");
                            int segundoChegada = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            athlete.finish(horaChegada, minutoChegada, segundoChegada);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Atleta não existe.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 6:
                    System.Environment.Exit(1);
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Opcao invalida.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Runner class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Marathon
{
    class Runner
    {
         static public int number;
         static public bool finished;
         static public int hours;
         static public int minutes;
         static public int secs;

        public Runner(int participationNumber)
        {
            number = participationNumber;
        }



        public int getNumber()
        {
            return number;
        }
        public void finish(int fHour, int fMinute, int fSecs)
        {
            hours = fHour;
            minutes = fMinute;
            secs = fSecs;
            finished = true;
        }

        public string toString()
        {
            return string.Format("Number: {0}, Finished:{1} Time:{2}:{3}:{4}", number, finished, hours, minutes, secs);

        }


    }


}
```

Professional Class

```
namespace Marathon

{
    class Professional : Runner
    {
        private int worldranking;

        public Professional(int worldRanking, int pNumber) : base (number)
        {
            number=pNumber;
            worldranking = worldRanking;
        }

        public string toString()
        {
            return string.Format("Number: {0}, Finished:{1} Time:{2}:{3}:{4}\nWorld Ranking: {5}", number, finished, hours, minutes, secs, worldranking);

        }
    }
}
```

Amateur Class

```
namespace Marathon

{
    class Amateur : Runner
    {
        static public SponsorshipForm sponsForm;

        public Amateur(int aNumber,SponsorshipForm SponsForm) : base(number)
        {
            aNumber = number;
            sponsForm = SponsForm;
        }

        public string toString()
        {
            return string.Format("Number: {0}, Finished:{1} Time:{2}:{3}:{4}", number, finished, hours, minutes, secs);

        }
```

Fancy Dresser Class

```
namespace Marathon

{
    class FancyDresser : Amateur
    {
        string costume;
    public FancyDresser(int fnumber, SponsorshipForm sponsorsForm, string pCostume) : base(number,sponsForm)
        {
            number = fnumber;
            sponsForm = sponsorsForm;
            costume = pCostume;
        }
    }
}
```

Not currently using SponsorshipForm class at the moment

Comment: Please include the rest of your code (where the loop body closes etc). Without this information, we can't reliably know what your code does.

Comment: Adding copies of last object is, indeed, a common problem. However, the segment of code that you included in the question is free from it, because it does not reuse `new`-ed objects. There must be some other branch of code that does.

Comment: Just posted the rest of the code. Thanks

Comment: What does your program output when you select option 4?

Comment: How do you know they are the last one you created? All the loop does is print out `athlete.ToString()` which, unless you overrode the `ToString` method, will just print out the name of the type.

Comment: It outputs the same object that was last added to the list, the number of times I added an object to the list.
Number: 2, Finished:False Time:0:0:0
Number: 2, Finished:False Time:0:0:0
Number: 2, Finished:False Time:0:0:0
I added 3 objects with different values

Comment: the ToString is a method created by myself that prints out the info from the object

Comment: My guess, without seeing the implementation of the classes, is that the `Number`, `Finished`, and `Time` properties have been declared as `static`. Can you add the definitions for `Runner` and its subclasses?

Comment: added the classes. thanks!

Comment: @HarrisonPaine is right. All your variables in the runner class are marked static, which means that all instances will share the same value.  Remove static from the definitions and you should be good to go.

Comment: that way i cant call number in base(number) in the child classes. any sugestions?

Comment: Your code is full of typos.  The constructor for "Amateur" should be: `public Amateur(int aNumber, ...): base(aNumber){ ... }`. You should be passing the `aNumber` value to the `base(int number)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are using static variables for no reason.
Simply change your code from:

```
    static public int number;
    static public bool finished;
    static public int hours;
    static public int minutes;
    static public int secs;

    public Runner(int participationNumber)
    {
        number = participationNumber;
    }
```

To:

```
    public int number;
    public bool finished;
    public int hours;
    public int minutes;
    public int secs;

    public Runner(int participationNumber)
    {
        number = participationNumber;
    }
```

And change the following signatures:

```
public Professional(int worldRanking, int pNumber) : base(pNumber)

public Amateur(int aNumber, SponsorshipForm SponsForm) : base(aNumber)

public FancyDresser(int fnumber, SponsorshipForm sponsorsForm, string pCostume) : base(fnumber, sponsForm)
```

Remember, a static property will be shared between every instance of that class, you don't want it.

Check SponsorshipForm, being static it will as well be unique.